# How to run python scripts (for API calls) to run every week?

Tags: python, api, cron

I am currently writing Python scripts and accessing data from an API. The data I get from this API is then saved on an AWS RDS SQL Server. I was wondering if there is a way to run these scripts on particular days without the need of having my computer on. Is there a remote server I can be running these for free? Or is this something I can use a Cron Job for (from my understanding Cron Jobs can only be run from my own machine). This data is being used for a class project website and so I need to be getting the latest data from the API on particular days automatically.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: AWS Lambda functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AWS already, give AWS lambda a try. You can create a CRON trigger there (as well as many others).

It works like this:

1. You provide a zip file which contains all necessary code. It will use one single function (which you can specify) as an entry point. It has to be either Python 2.7 or Python 3.6
2. The zip file has to contain everything, including dependencies. Virtualenv is your friend to create that. Numpy is no problem
3. Define the triggers (CRON, in your case)
4. Define maximum resources (memory, execution time)

It's not free, but very cheap.

Gotchas:

- Lambda itself is stateless. Writing to a local file will not have any effect. Commonly you write to S3.
- Resource limits! At most it can execute 5min! Also the zip file size is limited.
- One execution is guaranteed, bit but not exaktly one

Comment: Just found AWS Lambda a few minutes ago as well. I am relatively new to using AWS, and additional tips/guide I should follow for using AWS Lambda? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to AWS Lambda is [Crono](https://www.crono.com/). Crono is a simpler REST API that lets you manage time-based jobs programmatically.